# Weekly Steps Retrieved through Google Fit Android API doesn't match with steps displayed in Google Fit Official App

Tags: android, android-studio, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

I am trying to retreive user's weekly steps data from google fit API but I am getting different steps count result from official google fit App data. for example : steps retrieved through google fit api for thursday are **5244** while in official google fit app the count for thursday's step is **5134**. Steps count for every day of the week is a little different but I want exact results. I am using google fit History API to retrieve weekly steps count and display in a bar chart.
My code looks like this:

```
    fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build();

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void invokeHistoryApiForWeeklySteps() {


    // Read the data that's been collected throughout the past week.
    ZonedDateTime endTime = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        endTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
    ZonedDateTime startTime = endTime.minusWeeks(1);

    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: $startTime");
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: $endTime");

    DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime.toEpochSecond(), endTime.toEpochSecond(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();


    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions))
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(response -> {


                // The aggregate query puts datasets into buckets, so convert to a
                // single list of datasets
                for (Bucket bucket : response.getBuckets()) {

                    //convert days in bucket to milliseconds
                    long days = bucket.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    //convert milliseconds to date
                    Date stepsDate = new Date(days);
                    //convert date to day of the week eg: monday, tuesday etc
                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
                    String weekday = df.format(stepsDate);

                    Log.i(TAG, stepsDate.toString());
                    theDates.add(weekday);

                    for (DataSet dataSet : bucket.getDataSets()) {
                        totalAvgSteps.add(dumpDataSet(dataSet));



                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, theDates.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, totalAvgSteps.toString());
                displayBarChart();
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                    Log.w(TAG, "There was an error reading data from Google Fit", e));

}

    private int dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: ${dataSet.dataType.name}");
    int totalSteps = 0;
    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
        Log.i(TAG, "\tType: ${dp.dataType.name}");
        Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: ${dp.getStartTimeString()}");
        Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: ${dp.getEndTimeString()}");


        for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            totalSteps += dp.getValue(field).asInt();

            Log.i(TAG, "\tfield: " + fieldName + "value: " + dp.getValue(field));

        }
    }
    return totalSteps;
}
```

Here is what I get in result by this code:

My Code Result:

[image]

And this is what data looks like in google Fit Official App

Steps Count In Google Fit App:

[image]

Steps Count in Google Fit App:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I fixed the problem of steps count difference and thus sharing here if it can help someone else as well.
The mistake I was doing is I wasn't calculating the data from yesterday's midnight 12:00 am to last week's midnight 12:00 am which caused the difference in the number of steps for every day.
Here is the right date and time calculation:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(endTime));
    Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(startTime) );
```

and We need to change the data request a little bit where I was requesting it in seconds now I am requesting that in milliseconds which is giving me the exact data as google fit official app.

```
 DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

The rest of the code is as it is as I posted it in the question.